# ubuntu server: login with new created user > get dollar shell

Tags: server, users, adduser

when I create a new user in Ubuntu Server and then try to login with the new user I get an error message.

In one case Ubuntu tells me that the home directory of the user doesn't exist when I login and Ubuntu then shows me a dollar shell.
In the other case, when I create a home folder for the user, Ubuntu just shows me a dollar shell when I log in with the user.

I use: `useradd NAME`. I thought the home directory was automatically created when creating a user.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Regarding the $-prompt: what did you expect to see? That prompt is normal for the server version (since no desktop).

Comment: That question has been answered yesterday: `sudo useradd -d  /home/user -m user` is the correct commnand ;)

Comment: problem solved. thx for the help. Forgot something. Stupid. :)

Answer (score 3):

The command to have useradd create a home is

```
sudo useradd -d /home/user -m user
```

Where user (2 times) is your account name.

(The files in the new home directory are copied from the `/etc/skel` folder)

Comment: I tried the command you gave, but I still have the same problem. Creating the user is ok, but the problem begins after logging in with the created user. I just get the $-prompt. Normally it should be user@ubuntu:~$, what I see is just:$

Answer (score 1):

You can create a home directory by adding the `-d` flag.

```
  -d, --home HOME_DIR
           The new user will be created using HOME_DIR as the value for the
           user's login directory. The default is to append the LOGIN name to
           BASE_DIR and use that as the login directory name. The directory
           HOME_DIR does not have to exist but will not be created if it is
           missing.
```

The `$`  in the terminal indicates that you are not using the bash shell, where you are familiar with I guess. When creating a home dir I guess the problem is over. Otherwise you can switch change to bash with `which bash`.